How can i Conditional color a data frame with Knitr in R?
i have a data frame in R called df  :


library(tidyverse)
Var = c("abcd my name is helen efghi gklmno pqrstvw_1","abcd efghi gklmno my name is john pqrstvw_2","abcd efghi gklmno my name is fey pqrstvw_3",
        "abcd my name is george efghi gklmno pqrstvw_4","abcd efghi my name is mary gklmno pqrstvw_5","abcd efghi gklmno my name is nick pqrstvw_6",
        "abcd my name is daisy efghi gklmno pqrstvw_7")
val_1 = c(2,3.1,4,3.4,5,4,2.3)
val_2 = c(1.8,3.3,4,3.4,5,4,2.3)
val_3 = c(5,4.3,4,3.4,5,4,2.3)
val_4 = c(4,3.2,4,3.4,5,4,3)
df = tibble(Var,val_1,val_2,val_3,val_4);df

and looks like this :
A tibble: 7 × 5
  Var                                           val_1 val_2 val_3 val_4
  <chr>                                         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 abcd my name is helen efghi gklmno pqrstvw_1    2     1.8   5     4  
2 abcd efghi gklmno my name is john pqrstvw_2     3.1   3.3   4.3   3.2
3 abcd efghi gklmno my name is fey pqrstvw_3      4     4     4     4  
4 abcd my name is george efghi gklmno pqrstvw_4   3.4   3.4   3.4   3.4
5 abcd efghi my name is mary gklmno pqrstvw_5     5     5     5     5  
6 abcd efghi gklmno my name is nick pqrstvw_6     4     4     4     4  
7 abcd my name is daisy efghi gklmno pqrstvw_7    2.3   2.3   2.3   3  


i want to print it in pdf format with knitr package as tabular  in latex format.
knitr::kable(df, format = "latex")

I want to add some colouring in the resulting data table. For example i want all the column names to be gray (background the letters to remain black) . And the cells values (background values black) to be coloured according to a condition: if x<3 yellow, if x>=3 and x<4 then red and if x>4.5 then blue. How can i do this in R with knitr package and this colouring table to appear in pdf with rmarkdown

@SamR how I can apply across all columns the same conditional colouring?Apart from having the columns names background grey?

I think the second answer to the linked question does exactly that using mutate(across()). Is that not what you mean?

@SamR yes.And what about the grey column names ?

A table is zero-indexed starting from the header in the kableExtra world so my_table |> kableExtra::row_spec(0, background = "grey")

@SamR i cannot find a proper way to do the rest.I am sorry.

Can you explain how your question above is different to your question here? I was thinking I could write an answer but I don't know if they should be marked as duplicates, or if they're different from each other and require different solutions. I can't see an obvious difference but perhaps I'm missing something.

@SamR the difference is that i cannot do it with KableExtra package

Just to be clear - in the other question you can use kableExtra but in this one you cannot use any additional packages?

@SamR yes here i am only interested in kableextra package. Formattable do not work in latex for pdf rendering in R in my laptotp.That's why i insist on this example with KableExtra.

Once you generate the latex, how are you rendering the pdf? Are you using pandoc / rmarkdown / Quarto / something else?

@SamR rmarkdown with xelatex machine in options and MikTex
